# Can SAS do as STATA esttab?

Tags: sas

STATA has a wonderful code **esttab** to report multiple regressions in one table. Each column is a regression and each row is a variable.
Can SAS do the same thing? I only can get something in SAS like the following. However, the table is not so beautiful as esttab.

Thanks in advance.

```
data error;
input Y X1 X2 X3 ;
datalines;
4   5  6  7
6   6  5  9
9   8  8  8
10  10 2 1
4   4 2 2 
6   8 3 5 
4   4 6 7
7   9 8 8 
8   8 5 5
7   5 6 7
9  8 9 8
0 2 5 8
6 6 8 7
1 2 5 4
 5 6 5 8
 6 6 8 9
 7 7 8 2
 5 5 8 2
 5 8 7 8
run;
PROC PRINT;RUN;

   proc reg data=error outest=est tableout alpha=0.1;
M1: MODEL Y =  X1 X2      / noprint;
M2: MODEL Y =  X2 X3      / noprint;
M3: MODEL Y =  X1 X3      / noprint;
M4: MODEL Y =  X1 X2   X3    / noprint;
   proc print data=est;
   run;
```

Comment: Please share the output screenshot when you use `Esttab` in `Stata`. That'll help.

Comment: Please describe the output you would like, and explain how it is different than what you are getting from PROC REG.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used `Stata` but knew it as a part of my project. Unfortunately, there's no good way to do it using `SAS`. You can try installing and using latest [`Tagsets`](http://support.sas.com/rnd/base/ods/odsmarkup) to get the desired output. `excltags.tpl` should help in this case.

Like,

```
ods path work.tmplmst(update) ;
filename tagset url 'http://support.sas.com/rnd/base/ods/odsmarkup/excltags.tpl';
%include tagset;
```

Above installs `Tagsets` and stores the same in `Work`. This will not disrupt already installed tagsets on the system. Also, this step need to be done everytime you open a new `SAS` session.

```
    ods listing close;
    ods tagsets.ExcelXP file='Excelxp.xml';
#Your Code#
    proc reg data=error outest=est tableout alpha=0.1;
    M1: MODEL Y =  X1 X2      / noprint;
    M2: MODEL Y =  X2 X3      / noprint;
    M3: MODEL Y =  X1 X3      / noprint;
    M4: MODEL Y =  X1 X2   X3    / noprint;
    proc print data=est;
    run;
#Your Code#
    ods tagsets.ExcelXP close;
```

I am currently on my home desktop and it dont have `SAS` installed and i've not given it a try. This should export result of regressions into a table that includes coefficients,significance level etc. into Excel.

Let me know if this works. Also, please refer to this [Document](https://support.sas.com/rnd/base/ods/templateFAQ/Excel1.pdf) for more information.

Comment: Thank you @Praneeth Kumar. You give me the inspiration. I think I find the answer to the quest.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Praneeth Kumar's inspiration. I found the related information from http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/code/ummary-table-for-multiple-regression-models/

I change it to fit my needs.

```
/*1*//*set the formation*/
proc format;           
    picture stderrf (round)       
        low-high=' 9.9999)' (prefix='(')                                
            .=' ';                                                  
run;
/*2*//*run the several regressions and turn the results to a dataset*/
ods output ParameterEstimates (persist)=t;                     
 PROC REG DATA=error;
 M1: MODEL Y =  X1 X2    ;
M2: MODEL Y =  X2 X3    ;
M3: MODEL Y =  X1 X3     ;
M4: MODEL Y =  X1 X2   X3   ;
run;                                                                
 ods output close;                                                   

proc print data=t;                                                  
run;
   /*3*//*use the formation and the dataset change into a table*/
proc tabulate data=t noseps;      
  class model variable;                      
  var estimate Probt;     
  table variable=''*(estimate =' '*sum=' '                          
                     Probt=' '*sum=' '*F=stderrf.),                
         model=' '                                                  
          / box=[label="Parameter"] rts=15 row=float misstext=' '; 
run;
```